# How do you call an insertion sort from it's own class to assort an array in a seperate class, for JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, insertion-sort

I am really struggling with figuring out how to call my insertion sort code from my insertion class into a test class that has an array that is ready to be sorted by it. This array is being sorted by a bubble sort already. Any ideas?

```
public class InsertionSort 
{

public static void sort(Comparable[] a) 
{
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) 
        {
            if (a[j-1].compareTo(a[j]) > 0) 
            {
                exch(a, j-1, j);
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Above is the insertion Sort code below is the TestSort that holds the array and should call the insertion sort

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestSort
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    int[] anArray ={26,45,67,89,23,47,32,98};
     BubbleSort.bubbleSort(anArray);
     InsertionSort.sort(anArray);


      for(int i=0; i< anArray.length; i++){

     System.out.print(anArray[i] + " ");
   }
 }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing it already.

Comment: If bubble sort works correctly then another line won't change anything in the array because it will be already sorted. You should assign results to some variable or remove one sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something;

1. Your method `InsertionSort.sort(..)` should return the array sorted.
2. You have to assign the result to another variable in your main method

---

**Note**

`Comparable[]` is not `int[]`, `int[]` cannot be converted to `Comparable[]`

**Edit**

Here is how your code should look like :

```
public class InsertionSort {

    public static Comparable[] sort(Comparable[] a) {
//-------------------^^-----sort method should return Comparable[] and not void
        //...your code here
        return a;//<<-----------return the result
    }
}

public class TestSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparable[] anArray = {26, 45, 67, 89, 23, 47, 32, 98};
//---------^^-----------Your array should be of type Comparable[] not int[]
        //...
        anArray = InsertionSort.sort(anArray);
//---------^^---^-----------assight the result of your method
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example please? :)

Comment: check my edit @Avrielle'Avy'Rouse i'm not sure what your program should do but it is logic to be like this

Comment: Hi YCF , the testsort should call the insertion sort to sort anArray. Thanks for your help! I'm going to try now!